# iOS: Registering for dynamic UTIs

Tags: ios, dynamic, uti

I am developing an application that will be capable of handling multiple file types. To accomplish this, I have registered the UTIs corresponding to the file types in my `info.plist` file. However, there are a few file types, such as .pub & .indd, for which mdls generates a dynamic UTI (dyn.something).

My question is, how do I register for such types? As far as I can understand, as these are not file types defined by my application (custom file types such as `com.mycomp.myapp`), I should not be required to export UTIs.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched about this a lot. It seems that these file types are not supported by iOS (even Mac OS X).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible for 3rd party apps. The URIs must be specified in the info.plist which is built into the bundle.

Comment: Thanks Roger! So, is it possible to register & export UTIs for such a file type as my custom type (lets say I call it com.mycomp.pub)? Because I have noticed that when I try to open these file types (there are present as email attachments), the DropBox (3rd party) app is able to register & open such files.

Comment: Roger, while going through your comment again, I felt that I was not able to frame my question properly. I am NOT trying to dynamically add/remove UTIs associated with my app. The UTIs are fixed and specified in info.plist. My question was regarding dynamic UTIs (which are dynamically generated by the OS and can vary from one system to another. They are of the form dyn.somerandomstring). How could I register such a UTI in the info.plist?

Answer (score 0):

You should check this Q&A page on how to export custom UTI type.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html

Even if files of such type might have system UTI type, you can register your own one by some unique name, e.g.

com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}.x-pub